# why do we use brakets to get keys and ,not to get values

Tags: python, pandas, key

I have a question in this example:

```
Country1 = {'Japan': 80, 'China': 450, 'India': 200, 'USA': 250}
Country2 = {'Brazil': 100,'China': 500, 'India': 210,'USA': 260}

# Convert into Pandas Series

sales_Q1 = pd.Series(Country1)
sales_Q2 = pd.Series(Country2)

sales_Q1.keys()  #=====> Index(['Japan', 'China', 'India', 'USA'], dtype='object')
sales_Q1.values  #=====> array([ 80, 450, 200, 250], dtype=int64)
```

Question: Why do we use brackets to get keys and not to get values?

Comment: You can also use `sales_Q1.to_numpy()` in place of `sales_Q1.values`, one difference is that `to_numpy()` will return a new object, while `values` can be used as an accessor: `sales_Q1.values[0] += 1`

Comment: Because thats's how the API has been designed. `.keys()` is the same as `.index`. Likely it has been added to mimic the behaviour of dicts, for whatever reason.

Comment: call with brackets like `.keys()` mean it is a method, without like `.values` means it is an attribute (or property https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) ... as to why, it is just a choice of the library author. It does seem weird to me that `keys` and `values` are not accessed in the same way, but Pandas is a very popular library so probably there is some rationale for that decision

Answer (score 1):

Using `.keys()` known as a method, and `.values` known as an attribute.

Here's a simple example to give you clearance about what are method and attributes.

```
# when you call pandas you actually call its class (in this example called Greeting)
class Greeting:

  def __init__(self, name="adam"):
    # This is example of attribute
    self.name = name

  def hello(self):
    # This is example of method
    print("hello " + self.name)

pd = Greeting()
# example of set attribute
pd.name = "Edward"

# This is example of calling attribute
print(pd.name)
# This is example of calling method
print(pd.hello())
```

So to answer your question why do we use parentheses to get keys and not to get values, it's because of the `pandas` codebase design, that uses `.keys()` as method and `.values` as attribute

Comment: thank's Felix Filipi